# How to go home in terminal?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some doubts, how to go previous path in terminal.for example. >home\username\
I need to go >home. Its directory or user\path.
Help me out this.

Comment: Yes...what is diff between su\sudo\root user...i enter sudo username...its said invalid manual entry, root also gaving this error

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory is `/home/username` and you want to go up one level to `/home`, all you have to do is execute `cd ..`.